# Object.defineProperty issue - TypeError: cookieStore.getAll is not a function

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I am using `Object.defineProperty` to detect API calls made. But I get a "Failed error" for the actual function once I run the code.

Here is the piece of code I am making the API call.

```
function get_cookie() {
  console.log(cookieStore)
  try {
    // try to get all cookies
    cookieStore.getAll()
    .then(function(cookies)
    {
      console.log(cookies)
    })
  } catch(e) {
    console.error(`Failed `)
  }
}
// call the function
get_cookie()
```

And here is the detection function(where the problem lies probably),

```
function traceCookieStore() {
    cookieStore.getAll()
    .then(function(cookies)
    {
      // console.log(cookies);
      Object.defineProperty(CookieStore.prototype, 'getAll',{
        get: function(){
          cookiestoreTrace.push({[CookieStore.prototype.constructor.name]: 'cookieStore.getAll()'});
          console.log("cookiestoreTrace->",cookiestoreTrace);


         return cookie;
        }
      })
    })


}  

traceCookieStore();
```

The wording of the error is

> TypeError: cookieStore.getAll is not a function

I must admit I am not really good with JS promises so I am a little at loss on how to debug this issue.

Edit 1: I am running `get_cookie()` function from the web worker context to get the cookies for that domain by making the API call to `cookieStore.getAll`, and this function is working fine.
The function, `traceCookieStore()` is to detect if an API call is made to `cookieStore.getAll`, this will sort of hook the API call and then return the value of `getAll` (i.e cookies).

I am sorry, if my initial information was not enough, as I mentioned I am new to Javascript and still learning the ins-and-outs of it.

Edit 2: CookieStore is API provided to set and get cookies asynchronously from the page and worker context. Reference [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CookieStore)

Comment: What is the actual objective here?  Without referencing your code, please describe in words what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Also, what is `cookieStore`?  Is this something you get from some module?

Comment: You could try printing out `e.message` too - I bet the error message would give you helpful information about what's going on. (or just remove that try-catch entirely - it doesn't look like it's adding any value)

Comment: Make sure `getAll` exists before calling it. Code  seems to be calling the `getAll` method before adding it to `cookieStore.prototoype` inside  a call to `traceCookieStore` -  which also calls `getAll` before defining it as a property.

Comment: And the `get` function  doesn't return create a promise to return.

Comment: @jfriend00 Hey, sorry for the delay but I posted this almost when I was almost finishing my work yesterday, there was no replies/comments for next half an hour so I went offline and just woke up to read the post again. Still I am sorry if that bothers you.

Comment: @jfriend00 For rest of your questions, I have updated the post itself.

Comment: @traktor Thanks for pointing it out. I actually define getAll as property first and then call the function. So the correct order of calling these functions are first ->'traceCookieStore()' and then->'get_cookie'

Answer (score 0):

**CookieStore Hook**

It is rarely, if ever, advisable to modify prototype properties of global constructors and objects (noting `CookieStore` is an object, not a constructor). To hook the `getAll` method of the `CookieStore` global object, hook the method *before*  calling `getAll`, rather than inside a `cookieStore.getAll` call which may suffer from timing issues or fail because `cookieStore` doesn't have a `getAll` method.

The following example uses an interface class to return a `cookieStore` object which behaves like `CookieStore` except it has methods to hook and unhook the `getAll` method. Developing a [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) object of `CookieStore` to create hooks when accessing it directly (without creating a separately hooked `cookieStore` object) is another alternative.

```js
if( typeof CookieStore === "undefined") { // for local testing
    console.log( "Creating CookieStore object for testing");
    var CookieStore = {
        getAll() {return Promise.resolve( ["cookie1", "cookie2", "cookie3"]);}
    };
}

class CookieHooker {
    constructor() {
       if( typeof CookieStore === "undefined") {
           throw Error("Secure domain required");
       }
       this.cookieStore = Object.create( CookieStore);
       this.cookieStore.hookGetAll = this.hookGetAll.bind(this);
       this.cookieStore.unhookGetAll = this.unhookGetAll.bind(this);
    }
    hookGetAll( hookFunction) {
        this.cookieStore.getAll = function(){
             return hookFunction(CookieStore.getAll());
        };
    }
    unhookGetAll() {
        delete this.cookieStore.getAll;
    }
}

const {cookieStore} = new CookieHooker;
const cookieStoreTrace = [];
const traceCookieStore = function(listPromise) {
      return listPromise.then( list => {
         cookieStoreTrace.push(list); // or whatever;
         console.log( `from traceCookieStore(), you have ${list?.length||0} cookies`);
         return list;
      });
}

cookieStore.hookGetAll( traceCookieStore);
cookieStore.getAll()
.then( list => console.log( "from cookieStore.getAll(), list:", list) );
```

**About `Object.create`**

`Object.create` creates an object with its prototype chain set to the method's first argument. The `cookieStore` object in the example

- **inherits** methods and properties of `CookieStore`,
- **stores** any methods added to it as own properties.

Answer (score 0):

Following is the template of the code that helped me resolve this issue.

```
var traceCookieStore = function(obj, propKey) {
  
    var propOriginal = obj[propKey];
    Object.defineProperty(obj, prop, {
      "get": function(){
        //do what you want here
        return propOriginal;

      }
    }) 
}
```

I am sharing this here since I did not find any relevant answer on Stackoverflow and this just might help someone. Good Luck!